# Button in Phaser doesn't work

Tags: jquery, button, phaser-framework

I have a code, just a button created via Phaser:

```javascript
//---------------------------------Boot
module.exports = {

 init: function() {
    closeButton = game.add.button(w/1.47, h/1.272, 'close', this.closeProfile, this);
    closeButton.fixedToCamera = true;
    closeButton.inputEnabled = true;
 },

 closeProfile: function() {
    alert('asd')
    close.key = 'img/profile/closePress.png';
 }
};
```

Module.exports - this is Browserify

in the main file there is another code:

```javascript
 //---------------------------------Main
 window.game = new Phaser.Game((h > w) ? h : w, (h > w) ? w : h, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game', {render:render});

var ship;
var cursors;
var sun1;
var rc;
var space;

var profile;
var closeButton, holdLeft, holdRight, avaProfile;

game.state.add('Boot', require('./states/boot.js'));
game.state.add('Play', require('./states/play.js'));
game.state.start('Boot');
```

And button doesn't call a function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm also pretty new at phaser but I would try adding an on click event to the button as follows.

```
closeButton.inputEnabled = true;
closeButton.events.onInputDown.add(onDown,this);
function onDown(sprite,pointer){
     Some function code here;
 };
```

Explanation: the onDown is the name of the function to be called, the this keyword refers to the input method used. then on the function you pass over the sprite (or in this case the button clicked) and the input method used (pointer).
Good luck hope that helps a little.

Comment: oh just noticed this question is pretty old, sorry if you already got the answer a long time ago good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

```
 var button;
 button = game.add.button(200, 200, 'button', functionName, game);
```

**And put it in the create function**.  The init function is for stuff like resizing.